# location.href not working after ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, redirect, xmlhttprequest

I have an form that when it sumits the data it echo "success", I used the success to trigger a redirect to another page but it is not working. I have tried everything. The else statement works fine but whatever i write in the if(data == "success") is not working including console.log and alert.`

```
continueBtn.onclick = () =>{
    //Ajax code
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();// this will create a new XML Object
    xhr.open("POST", "php/signup.php", true );
    xhr.onload = () =>{
        if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE){
            if(xhr.status === 200){
                let data = xhr.response;
                if(data == "success"){
                    errorTxt.textContent = "Thuinsowofnd wsikenon";
                    window.location.href = 'users.php';
                }else{
                    errorTxt.textContent = data;
                    errorTxt.style.display = "block";
                    
                }
            }
        }

    }
    //let's send form data through Ajax to Php
    let formData =new FormData(form);//this will create a new form object
    xhr.send(formData);// this will the form data
```

`

I have tried using windows.location.href = "users.php" but it still doesn't work

Comment: If you log `data` outside of the if statement what do you get?

Comment: It says undefined when I console log outside of the if statement

Comment: The data is empty so the redirect won't work as the code in the if block is not going to be executed.